# MPMoviePlayerController blank frame after seeking to particular time-line

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, frame, seek

I am developing an iPhone application in which I play a video using **MPMoviePlayerController**. I use custom controls to play the video.

I have a slider that shows video time line. Using this user can seek the movie to any time-line of the movie.

When user continuously moves the slider:

1. Pause the video only for first time; `[MPMoviePlayerController-obj pause]`
2. `MPMoviePlayerController-obj.currentPlaybackTime = slider.value`

When slider action ends:

1. Play the video; `[MPMoviePlayerController-obj play]`

This plays the movie from the position where user had left the slider. But, it leads to blank frame when movie completes playing. This defect occurs randomly; i.e not for all the seek'd time.

What is the reason for getting the blank frame? How do I solve this?

Comment: I also noticed while debugging that, if I do not set MPMoviePlayerController-obj.currentPlaybackTime when user continuously moves the slider, it works fine. But, I want to do that because user needs to view the frame when he set the time-line by moving the slider.

Comment: Also, when the movie completes playing (MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification), the currentPlaybackTime of the MPmoviePlayerController is 0 if the problem exists; otherwise it is equal to duration of the movie. Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will work, but try setting the `initialPlaybackTime` to either the `slider.value` or to `currentPlaybackTime`.

Comment: I have already tried setting initialPlaybackTime and endPlaybackTime to slide (min and max value) + currentPlaybackTime of MPMoviePlayerController. But, still the problem exists. Also, I tried the following: After [MPMoviePlayerController-obj play], I again tried setting currentPlaybackTime to slide.value. Now, there is not black frame issue. But, when the slider action ends the frame repeats (one due to Play and one more when I set currentPlaybackTime). Will this help someone to help me out?

Comment: @Till, my bad. I'll remove that note. I missed that piece of documentation.

Comment: From my experience, initialPlaybackTime does not work when using streams - I did not thoroughly investigate but using it in a brief test did not result into a proper initial seek. My solution was using currentPlaybackTime once the playbackState changed to playing.

Comment: Not to give @Ben negative marking, he just showed an option though he was not sure & he should not be punished.

Answer (score 2):

For being sure that your content is not flawed, hence possibly triggering that issue, you should try to replicate your faulty `MPMoviePlayerController` results using Apple's reference video content.

- HTTP-Streaming: [bipbop.m3u8](http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8)
- Progressive Download & Local
  Playback: [sample_mpeg4.mp4](http://a1408.g.akamai.net/5/1408/1388/2005110405/1a1a1ad948be278cff2d96046ad90768d848b41947aa1986/sample_mpeg4.mp4.zip)

I have personally observed many issues in connection with improper encoding. Weird things tend to happen when working with lossy compressed content. This is true for video (i-frames vs. p-frames) as well as audio (variable bitrate).

One being improper playback durations being reported. Such issue may result into an unexpected finished-state. I have seen cases where `MPMoviePlayerController` still shows a bunch of seconds to play even though the actual video has obviously finished. Those cases occur frequently once the user seeks around within the video.

Once you made sure that the issue occurs using the given sample files as well, you should file a bug-report.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try this out. In response to 'One being improper playback durations being reported', can we use AVFoundation calls to generate the movie duration

Comment: But, we cannot change the movie duration property of MPMoviePlayerController. How do I verify if this is the problem causing?

Comment: I have given you some options on content that is properly encoded. Does that content behave any different from your own content?